# How to get package name in script?

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm doing a short post package install/update script to copy some files from the `vendor` directory into my `public` one.

Following the example of the `composer` site however when I execute it I get an error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Composer\DependencyResolver\Operation\UpdateOperation::getPackage() in S:\Projects\composer-scripts\FileCopy.php on line 17

The code is:

```
namespace composer-scipts;

use Composer\Script\Event;

class FileCopy
{
    public static function postPackageInstall( Event $event )
    {
        $packageName = $event->getOperation()->getPackage()->getName();

        echo "$packageName\n";
    }

    public static function postPackageUpdate( Event $event )
    {
        $packageName = $event->getOperation()->getPackage()->getName();

        echo "$packageName\n";
    }
}
```

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: @Ant not sure what you mean?  It is a script as per https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md

Comment: Look in the Defining scripts# section to see what I mean.

Comment: Ok, the snippet from the `composer.json` is:

    "psr-4": {
        "composer-scripts": "vendor/wip/composer-scripts"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-package-install": [
            "FileCopy::postPackageInstall"
        ],
        "post-package-update": [
            "FileCopy::postPackageUpdate"
        ]
    }

Comment: see this - https://getcomposer.org/apidoc/master/Composer/DependencyResolver/Operation/UpdateOperation.html

Comment: Ok, changing to getInitialPackage() seems to have done the trick, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following further testing I have identified the issue, which is essentially due to two different interfaces having the same/a similar method but with different signatures.  Thusly I have ended up with:

```
public static function postPackageInstall( Event $event )
{
    $packageName = $event->getOperation()->getPackage()->getName();

    if( $packageName == 'twbs/bootstrap' )
    {
        self::copyFiles();
    }
}

public static function postPackageUpdate( Event $event )
{
    $packageName = $event->getOperation()->getInitialPackage()->getName();

    if( $packageName == 'twbs/bootstrap' )
    {
        self::copyFiles();
    }
}
```

So, postPackageInstall uses `getPackage()` where-as postPackageUpdate uses `getInitialPackage()`.